# escaping variables in vba code

Tags: vba, excel

Could some please help me to escape the variables in the function. I don't get it:

```
Cells(5, fieldextsales).FormulaLocal = "=SUMMEWENNS(Rawdata!K2:K" & maxnumrows & ";Rawdata!I2:I" & maxnumrows & ";""bezahlt"";Rawdata!A2:A" & maxnumrows & ";"">= "&DATWERT(""& weekstart &" 00:00")";Rawdata!A2:A" & maxnumrows & ";""<= "&DATWERT(""& weekend & " 23:59"))
```

EDIT
The hardcoded working formula is this:

```
=SUMMEWENNS(Rawdata!K2:K3446;Rawdata!I2:I3446;"bezahlt";Rawdata!A2:A3446;">="&DATWERT("18.03.2013 00:00");Rawdata!A2:A3446;"<="&DATWERT("24.03.2013 23:59"))
```

I just want to insert variables for the dates

```
"18.03.2013 00:00" => weekstart &" 00:00"
"24.03.2013 23:59" => weekend & " 23:59"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As rwisch45 noted, it's much better practice to use chr(34) than to try to escape double quotes, which involves adding, in an inevitably confusing way, extra double quotes.

I did want to suggest a modification in the formula, though. Since you are interested in conditioning the SUMWESSENS on particular date values, it makes sense to go ahead and evaluate them at the VBA level, rather than attempting to replicate the hard-coded formula for that purpose. I'm supplying the formula in two version: one which does the date calculation in VBA and another which replicates your hard-coded version, and does the date calculation in the worksheet.

One other change. As I find the Chr(34) a bit confusing to work with, I've introduced a substitute variable 'qq'. The following formula should, barring typos, be very nearly what you need.

#### Date Calculation in VBA

```
  qq = Chr(34)
  Cells(5, fieldextsales).FormulaLocal = "=SUMMEWENNS(RawData!K2:K" & _
                 maxnumrows & ";Rawdata!I2:I" & maxnumrows & ";" & qq & _
                 "bezahlt" & qq & ";Rawdata!A2:A" & maxnumrows & ";" & _
                 qq & ">=" & DATWERT(weekstart & " 00:00") * 1 & qq & _
                 ";RawData!A2:A" & maxnumrows & ";" & qq & "<=" & _
                 DATWERT(weekend & " 23:59") * 1 & qq & ")"
```

#### Date Calculation in Worksheet

```
  qq = Chr(34)
  Cells(5, fieldextsales).FormulaLocal = "=SUMMEWENNS(RawData!K2:K" & _
                maxnumrows & ",RawData!I2:I" & _
                maxnumrows & "," & qq & "bezahlt" & qq & ",RawData!A2:A" & _
                maxnumrows & "," & qq & ">=" & qq & "&DATWERT(" & qq & _
                weekstart & " 00:00" & qq & ")" & ",RawData!A2:A" & _
                maxnumrows & "," & qq & "<=" & qq & _
                "&DATWERT(" & qq & weekend & " 23:59" & qq & "))"
```

Comment: thx for the help. I get an error, that the Function DATWERT is not definded

Comment: See my second version of the formula, which I believe replicates your hard-coded version (with weekstart and weekend inserted).

Comment: Glad the formula did the job! It was just a matter of incrementally building up the code string to match the hard-coded version. If you could mark the answer as accepted, I would much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience with VBA and setting cell formulas, never use double quotes back to back. Instead, use chr(34) to represent double quotes inside of existing double quotes. So every place in your formula that has double quotes back to back should be replaced.

i.e.

```
";""bezahlt"
```

should be changed to

```
";" & chr(34) & "bezahlt" & chr(34)
```

So for your formula, try this:

```
Cells(5, fieldextsales).FormulaLocal = "=SUMMEWENNS(Rawdata!K2:K" & maxnumrows & ";Rawdata!I2:I" & maxnumrows & ";" & chr(34) & "bezahlt" & chr(34) & ";Rawdata!A2:A" & maxnumrows & ";>= " & DATWERT & "(" & weekstart & " 23:59);Rawdata!A2:A" & maxnumrows & ";<= " & DATWERT & "(" & weekend & " 23:59))"
```

Comment: thx. the "bezahlt" seems to work just fine. I have updated my original post with the hardcoded formula.